# Dictionary object not being initialized with data coming from client

Tags: javascript, c#

I am facing issue my server side dictionary object is not being initialized with data coming from client. What is wrong with of my following code? Do i need to mention more code here or someone can figure out based on the type of UserPermissions both on client and server side? 
**Is my dictionary declaration on client side wrong?**

This is my client side code which push dictionary objects in array and send to server,

```
$scope.studentDetail.UserPermissions = [];
var DataToBeSentToServer = { Key: Id, Value: [] };
for (var j in selectUsers) {
DataToBeSentToServer.Value.push(selectUsers[j].Id);
}
$scope.studentDetail.UserPermissions.push(DataToBeSentToServer);
```

Server Code:
The class is being initialized outside

```
public class Test{
    public Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>> UserPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I believe you are not creating instances of your dictionary class. Could you  create a dictionary fill in the values you need and then assign it to your studentDetail.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON object you send to the server is not a dictionary. It is an object with two properties :

```
public class MyJsonObject
{
    public Guid Key {get; set;}
    public Guid[] Value {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: how i can send Json object as dictionary than? please

Comment: I think you won't be able to send an object as a dictionary. You will be able to send an object, deserialize it as an object and then convert it to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

By default C# dictionary is being serialized into javascript object as it basically represents a hashmap. That means json output from your example `Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>>` will look like:

```
{
   "85dad90f-...": [
          "413516ea-...",
          "a38473df-...",
          "bee09890-..."
   ],
   "39454a68-...": [
          "f5510938-...",
          "57260cb7-...",
          "ed201f04-..."
   ],
   "a7bc6a9e-...": [
          "77689b7c-...",
          "baf3f74b-...",
          "735f77eb-..."
   ]
}
```

Therefore for deserialization from js you will have to create similar data structure. Note code snippet below is just to give you an idea about implementation.

```
// assuming your data model looks like this:
var users = [{
    username : 'John Doe',
    userid : 'f5510938-...',
    permissions : [
        { permission : 'view-landing-page', permissionid : '57260cb7-...' }, ...
    ]
}, ...]


// your implementation might look like:
var permissions = {};  // to be sent to server

foreach (var userIndex in users) {
    var user = users[userIndex];
    var key = user.userid;        //  Dictionary<Guid, <- dictionary key 

    if (!permissions[key]) {
        permissions[key] = [];
    }

    foreach(pIndex in user.permissions) {
        var permission = user.permissions[pIndex];

        permissions[key].push(permission.permissionid);
    }
}
```